# [jade] eigen3 not found build error

Tags: ros, eigen, catkin, eigen3, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even after following [jade/Migration for Eigen](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Migration#Eigen_CMake_Module_in_cmake_modules), I still see that `eigen3` is not found.

https://travis-ci.org/swri-robotics/marti_common/jobs/113832799#L3181-L3193

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package): 
  By not providing "FindEigen3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has 
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3", but 
  CMake did not find one. 
 
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" with any 
  of the following names: 
 
    Eigen3Config.cmake 
    eigen3-config.cmake 
 
  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set 
  "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3" 
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been 
  installed.
```

This may be happening only on `Travis CI`, using [Travis config from industrial_ci](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_ci/blob/master/.travis.yml) but I'm not sure yet.

Also similar/same [issue in a PR on `moveit_core`](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_core/pull/290) ([error on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/ros-planning/moveit_core/jobs/126462655#L2756)). [Someone reported that](https://github.com/swri-robotics/marti_common/issues/303#issuecomment-208510361) the build moves forward by combining `pkg_config` but I don't know if that's the best idea (and [didn't work for moveit_core](https://github.com/130s/moveit_core/pull/1)).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233344/%5Bjade%5D-eigen3-not-found-build-error/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-04-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! you can try adding to CMakeList.txt:

```
pkg_search_module(Eigen3 REQUIRED eigen3)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_definitions(${EIGEN3_DEFINITIONS})

if(NOT EIGEN3_FOUND)
    # Fallback to cmake_modules
    find_package(cmake_modules REQUIRED)
    find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
    set(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    set(EIGEN3_LIBRARIES ${EIGEN_LIBRARIES})  # Not strictly necessary as Eigen is head only
    # Possibly map additional variables to the EIGEN3_ prefix.
else()
    set(EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

catkin_package(
    ...
    DEPENDS Eigen
    ...
)

include_directories(
    ...
    ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

This setup works for me, I also got problems before with Eigen.

I hope it helps you.

---

Originally posted by [francisc0garcia](https://answers.ros.org/users/26890/francisc0garcia/) with karma: 51 on 2016-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1